# How to filter list file with type image ? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to filter list file with type image.But my code isn't working.

Here my code :

```
   local tFolder
   answer folder "Please choose the folder"
   put it into tFolder
   set the defaultFolder to tFolder
   if there is a folder tFolder then
      put the files into field "listFile"
      filter fld "listFile" with "JPEG file, *.jpg; *.jpeg"
   else
      beep
   end if
```

I want to filter all image type.How do I do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to edit the `answer file`file dialog to only display image data in the first place

`answer files "Select the images you wish to view:" with type "JPEG Images|jpg|JPEG"`

More Info:
http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/11491-how-can-i-restrict-an-answer-file-dialog-to-just-applications

Answer (score 0):

The following code lists all .jpg, .png (and .JPG, .PNG) files.  You can add more file types to the regular expression to list more types :)

```
put the files into field "listFile"
filter lines of field "listFile" with regex pattern "(?i)\.(jpg|png)$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the images of a directory.

```
function imagesFiles pPathFolder

   local tFiles, tListImagesFiles
   put files(pPathFolder) into tFiles

   filter lines of tFiles with "*[.png - .jpg - .jpeg - .gif - .bmp]" into tListImagesFiles

   return tListImagesFiles

end imagesFiles
```